# SSRS Data Driven query can do both Date to send and who to send to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Simple question... In SSRS when doing a data driven subscription- for the dataset, can you do a single query and include both date to send the report on and who to send it to?

An example would be if I want to send a report on a specific date and have the report sent to ziggy2561@gmail.com and a few others, is this possible or does the dataset query only allow either or on Date or who to send to?

Would you pull the data from two different tables if the dates are on one and the email addresses are on another? Would that work?

I have a couple of queries that work but they are only dates and I don't want to use the manual entry parameters in case there is an email address that needs to be updated or what have you.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 (and SSRS 2008 along with it) *completely* ran out of support well over 3 years ago; it is *long* past time your finalised and implemented your upgrade plans. 2008 is no longer a secure product.

Comment: Ah sorry, I never put down what version I am using... It is SSRS 2016 Enterprise.

Comment: Youve tagged [[tag:ssrs-2012]] now though. That's also completely unsupported.

Comment: @Larnu - there are few differences in functionality between the different versions of SSRS and don't affect many questions asked (including this one). On the other hand, SSRS seems to be the ONLY software that has only has a version (i.e. SQL Server and Oracle have both generic and versions) and SSRS's newer version's tag has fewer watchers to possibly answer (1400 for SSRS 2012, 144 for SSRS 2016). Maybe have a SSRS tag and get rid of the versions.

Comment: The dataset query for a data driven subscritopn is whatever you want it to be. The parameters for the report and who to send it to (email) etc., can come from any datasource and it will evaluate that data source at the time of running the subscription. The only thing not clear from your question is "date to send the report". This needs to be done via a schedule that will then trigger the subscription.

Comment: @HannoverFist [[tag:reporting-services]] is the non-versioned tag. Tagging random versions is *not* helpful. The OP initially tagged [[tag:ssrs-2008]] and now has tagged **both** [[tag:ssrs-2012]] and [[tag:ssrs-2016]]; this is just tag spam and they need to be correct. *Little* changing or not is irrelevant.

Comment: If you do want to send the report to different people on different days, the subscription would run every day and your data-driven query would return the email addresses for that day or no records if none. i.e. `WHERE REPORT_DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`